# Use quoted variable in group_by() %>% mutate() function call

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

**Reproducible example**

```
cats <-
  data.frame(
    name = c(letters[1:10]),
    weight = c(rnorm(5, 10, 1), rnorm(5, 20, 3)),
    type = c(rep("not_fat", 5), rep("fat", 5))
  )

get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {
  df %>%
    group_by(.[[group]]) %>%
    mutate(mean_stat = mean(.[[metric]])) %>%
    pull(mean_stat) %>%
    unique()
}

get_means(cats, metric = "weight", group = "type")
```

**What I tried**

I expect to get two values back, instead I get one value. It appears that the groupby is failing.

I tried everything including using quo(), eval() and substitute(), UQ(), !!, and a whole host of other things to try and make the stuff inside the group_by() work.

This seems awfully simple but I can't figure it out.

**Reasoning for code**

The decision for variables to be in quotes is because I am using them in ggplot aes_string() calls. I excluded ggplot code inside the function to simplify the code, otherwise it'd be easy because we could use standard evaluation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the "intended" way to do this in the tidyeval framework is to enter the arguments as names (rather than strings) and then quote the arguments using `enquo()`. `ggplot2` understands tidy evaluation operators so this works for `ggplot2` as well.

First, let's adapt the `dplyr` summary function in your example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {

  metric = enquo(metric)
  group = enquo(group)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!group) %>%
    summarise(!!paste0("mean_", as_label(metric)) := mean(!!metric))
}

get_means(cats, weight, type)
```

> ```
>   type    mean_weight
> 1 fat            20.0
> 2 not_fat        10.2
> ```

```
get_means(iris, Petal.Width, Species)
```

> ```
>   Species    mean_Petal.Width
> 1 setosa                0.246
> 2 versicolor            1.33 
> 3 virginica             2.03
> ```

Now add in ggplot:

```
get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {

  metric = enquo(metric)
  group = enquo(group)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!group) %>%
    summarise(mean_stat = mean(!!metric)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(!!group, mean_stat)) + 
      geom_point()
}

get_means(cats, weight, type)
```

[image]

I'm not sure what type of plot you have in mind, but you can plot the data and summary values using tidy evaluation. For example:

```
plot_func = function(data, metric, group) {

  metric = enquo(metric)
  group = enquo(group)

  data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(!!group, !!metric)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_point(data=. %>% 
                   group_by(!!group) %>%
                   summarise(!!metric := mean(!!metric)),
                 shape="_", colour="red", size=8) + 
      expand_limits(y=0) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand=expand_scale(mult=c(0,0.02)))
}

plot_func(cats, weight, type)
```

[image]

FYI, you can allow the function to take any number of grouping variables (including none) using the `...` argument and `enquos` instead of `enquo` (which also requires the use of `!!!` (unquote-splice) instead of `!!` (unquote)).

> ```
> get_means <- function(df, metric, ...) {
>
>   metric = enquo(metric)
>   groups = enquos(...)
>
>   df %>%
>     group_by(!!!groups) %>%
>     summarise(!!paste0("mean_", quo_text(metric)) := mean(!!metric))
> }
> ```

```
get_means(mtcars, mpg, cyl, vs)
```

> ```
>     cyl    vs mean_mpg
> 1     4     0     26  
> 2     4     1     26.7
> 3     6     0     20.6
> 4     6     1     19.1
> 5     8     0     15.1
> ```

```
get_means(mtcars, mpg)
```

> ```
>   mean_mpg
> 1     20.1
> ```

Comment: Nice answer! Just note that `quo_text()` is not appropriate in that context. It's a multi-line deparser. You can use `as_label()` or `as_name()` instead which are guaranteed to return a single-line string. The latter checks that its input is a variable name and not a function call, which is appropriate in many cases. Here `as_label()` would be fine because your function accepts inline transformations of variables, e.g. you can pass `get_means(mtcars, mpg * 100)`.

Comment: Thanks @lionel. Follow-up question: Like `quo_text()`, `as_label()` is an `rlang` function. My (potentially incorrect) impression is that the "average" tidyeval user shouldn't need to resort to `rlang` functions in the normal course of programming. Is there a way to generate dynamic compound column names using only functions in the standard `tidyverse` packages?

Comment: You're right. We are going to export `as_label()` in the tidyverse packages as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use strings for the names, as in your example, the correct way to do this is to convert the string to a symbol with `sym` and unquote with `!!`:

```
get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {
    df %>%
      group_by(!!sym(group)) %>%
      mutate(mean_stat = mean(!!sym(metric))) %>%
      pull(mean_stat) %>%
      unique()
}

get_means(cats, metric = "weight", group = "type")
[1] 10.06063 17.45906
```

If you want to use bare names in your function, then use `enquo` with `!!`:

```
get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {
    group <- enquo(group)
    metric <- enquo(metric)
    df %>%
      group_by(!!group) %>%
      mutate(mean_stat = mean(!!metric)) %>%
      pull(mean_stat) %>%
      unique()
}

get_means(cats, metric = weight, group = type)
[1] 10.06063 17.45906
```

---

**What is happening in your example?**

Interestingly `.[[group]]`, does work for grouping, but not the way you think. This subsets the stated column of the dataframe as a vector, then makes that a new variable that it groups on:

```
cats %>%
    group_by(.[['type']])

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   .[["type"]] [2]
   name  weight type    `.[["type"]]`
   <fct>  <dbl> <fct>   <fct>        
 1 a       9.60 not_fat not_fat      
 2 b       8.71 not_fat not_fat      
 3 c      12.0  not_fat not_fat      
 4 d       8.48 not_fat not_fat      
 5 e      11.5  not_fat not_fat      
 6 f      17.0  fat     fat          
 7 g      20.3  fat     fat          
 8 h      17.3  fat     fat          
 9 i      15.3  fat     fat          
10 j      17.4  fat     fat
```

Your problem comes with the `mutate` statement. Instead of selecting the, `mutate(mean_stat = mean(.[['weight']]))` simply extracts the `weight` column as a vector, computes the mean, and then assigns that single value to the new column

```
cats %>%
    group_by(.[['type']]) %>%
      mutate(mean_stat = mean(.[['weight']]))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   .[["type"]] [2]
   name  weight type    `.[["type"]]` mean_stat
   <fct>  <dbl> <fct>   <fct>             <dbl>
 1 a       9.60 not_fat not_fat            13.8
 2 b       8.71 not_fat not_fat            13.8
 3 c      12.0  not_fat not_fat            13.8
 4 d       8.48 not_fat not_fat            13.8
 5 e      11.5  not_fat not_fat            13.8
 6 f      17.0  fat     fat                13.8
 7 g      20.3  fat     fat                13.8
 8 h      17.3  fat     fat                13.8
 9 i      15.3  fat     fat                13.8
10 j      17.4  fat     fat                13.8
```

Comment: When is `sym` needed or not needed?  For example, you can do `group_by(!!group)` and it seems to work.

Comment: `sym` turns strings into symbols that you can use, `enquo` turns bare-name passed into a function into things that can be used. So if you pass `"type"` into the function, you need `sym`, but if you pass `type` in, use `enquo`

Comment: I think this got answered first.  So, commenting here.  It would be better to also show a function that can take both quoted and unquoted arguments

Answer (score 3):

The magrittr pronoun `.` represents the whole data, so you've taken the mean of all observations. Instead, use the tidy eval pronoun `.data` which represents the slice of data frame for the current group:

```
get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {
  df %>%
    group_by(.data[[group]]) %>%
    mutate(mean_stat = mean(.data[[metric]])) %>%
    pull(mean_stat) %>%
    unique()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with slight modification (if I understand correctly what you would like to achive):

```
 get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {
      df %>%
        group_by(!!sym(group)) %>%
        summarise(mean_stat = mean(!!sym(metric)))%>% pull(mean_stat)
    }
    get_means(cats, "weight", "type")

[1] 20.671772  9.305811
```

gives exactly same output as :

```
cats %>% group_by(type) %>% summarise(mean_stat=mean(weight)) %>%
  pull(mean_stat)

[1] 20.671772  9.305811
```

Comment: While equivalent most of the time, it is a bit safer to subset `.data` instead of unquoting symbols. That's because `.data[[col]]` checks that the variable exists in the data frame. Also it looks simpler to people who are not accustomed to tidy eval.

Answer (score 0):

using `*_at` functions :

```
library(dplyr)
get_means <- function(df, metric, group) {
  df %>%
    group_by_at(group) %>%
    mutate_at(metric,list(mean_stat = mean)) %>%
    pull(mean_stat) %>%
    unique()
}

get_means(cats, metric = "weight", group = "type")
# [1] 10.12927 20.40541
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
cats <-
  data.frame(
    name = c(letters[1:10]),
    weight = c(rnorm(5, 10, 1), rnorm(5, 20, 3)),
    type = c(rep("not_fat", 5), rep("fat", 5))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer using`across()`, `.data` and `{}` for renaming, and keeping the original function arguments as strings per OP:

```r
library(tidyverse)

get_means <- function(dat = mtcars, metric = "wt", group = "cyl") {
  dat %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(c(group)))) %>%
    summarise("{paste0('mean_',metric)}" := mean(.data[[metric]]), .groups="keep")
}

get_means()
```

see: `?dplyr_data_masking` for more detailed discussion.